# How to count by unique values a user ID has been exposed to by date?

Tags: python, pandas

Hi I have a table of sessions and registered table.
What i want to do is, first drop all rows in sessions table if sessionstable[dateKey] > registrationDate[dateKey]. Next is make a list of unique campaign and their combinations. Count number of user_id / total count that matches the combinations. The main idea here is to get an idea of the touchpoints and their contribution towards registration.  All 5 accounts were touched by one or more of the channels throughout their buyer journeys. In other words, the channels worked together by forming coalitions to increase the likelihood of opportunity conversion

sessions table

| dateKey | user_id | campaign |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-04-01 | 20 | facebook |
| 2022-04-02 | 20 | google |
| 2022-04-03 | 20 | facebook |
| 2022-04-03 | 20 | google |
| 2022-04-04 | 20 | tiktok |
| 2022-04-01 | 19 | google |
| 2022-04-02 | 18 | google |
| 2022-04-02 | 17 | google |
| 2022-04-03 | 17 | facebook |
| 2022-04-02 | 16 | google |
| 2022-04-03 | 16 | facebook |

Registration date

| dateKey | user_id |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-04-03 | 20 |
| 2022-04-03 | 19 |
| 2022-04-03 | 18 |
| 2022-04-02 | 17 |
| 2022-04-03 | 16 |

output is

| coalition | ratio |
| --- | --- |
| facebook | 0 |
| google | 0.6 |
| facebook+google | 0.2 |
| google+facebook | 0.2 |

so here's what i've got

```
#join tables
df = sessionstable.merge(registrationDate, on=user_id, how="left")
#return rows that is not bigger than datekey from registrationdate (datekey2)
df= df[df[dateKey]<df[datekey2]]

def subsets(S):
    '''Returns all possible subsets of the given set'''
    s = []
    for i in range(1, len(S)+1):
        s.extend(map(list, combinations(S, i)))
    return list(map('+'.join, s))

N = sorted({'Facebook', 'Google', 'LinkedIn'})
    
coalitions = subsets(N)
coalitions_lbl = ['S{}'.format(i) for i in range(1, len(coalitions)+1)]
```

how do I do a count on the coalition of items? And also how do I sort by datekey per user_id so that it matches?

Where ratio is registered users/ population(len(user_id.unique()).
The coalition 'Facebook+Google' resulted in 1 conversions from 5 opportunities,so has a conversion ratio of 1/5 = 0.2 (20%)

Comment: this question needs further clarification in order to craft a sound answer as long as 1) your code can't work in a python environment, 2) it's not clear how to reach the output table from the input tables (what happened to the tiktok row from the input in the output?)

Comment: hi the S is the subset lists, updated in the code above.

Comment: hi @lemon for the tiktok row for user id 20, since 20 regist date is on the 2022-04-03 and the tiktok is on 2022-04-04, the row is dropped, hence the df[df[dateKey]<df[datekey2]]